# Trying to change TextView String

Tags: android, string, settext

I´ve been looking for answers, and have tried a lot of things, but nothing is working...

So, Im doing what I think is a simple app (I just started learning)

So I have an activity sending a couple of string to another where a couple of TextViews should chnage ther values to the new String, but this is not happening. Here you have the code:

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);


        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String mail = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.MAIL);
        String password = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.PASSWORD);

        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_login);
        TextView displayMailSetter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mailView);
        displayMailSetter.setText(mail);
        displayMailSetter.postInvalidate();

        TextView displayPasswordSetter = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.passwordView);
        displayPasswordSetter.setText(password);
        displayPasswordSetter.postInvalidate();

        displayMailSetter.postInvalidate();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    }
}
```

Comment: You do not need to call postInvalidate() in onCreate. postInvalidate() means that the view has changed and needs to be redrawn, but in onCreate, no drawing has been done yet (AND postInvalidate is for use on a non-UI thread).

Comment: Then I do not understand how it works. I have a copule of TextViews, just setted in the XML for Position conveniences. With no text on them, here I change their values, but its not being updated in the emulator. I tried giving some default values in the xml, and those appears, so it seems its not updating the GUI (There is no NullPointer error)

Answer (score 1):

Try taking out these lines of code:

```
displayMailSetter.postInvalidate();
// Don't take out your displayPasswordSetter initilization and setText

displayPasswordSetter.postInvalidate();

displayMailSetter.postInvalidate();

setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
```

Change these lines of code:

```
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
```

to

```
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_login);
```

and take out the origional (right under the intents).

```
setContentView(R.layout.fragment_login);
```

The problem was that you were setting the layout to 3 different layouts. The first and third were the same layout, but didn't have the TextViews. The first and third are unnessecary, you should only set the layout once. Once you set it to fragment_login, the layout had the TextViews, set the text of them, but the layout was then changed to a layout without the TextViews.

Comment: If I remove the setContentView(R.layout.activity_login); fro mthe end, the app crashes

Comment: Can you post your LogCat when you take out the end setContentView?

Comment: @user2948787 You have THREE calls to setContentView. Why do you have so many? Every time you call that, it reinflates your view hierarchy with the defaults, invalidating whatever you set your view values to.

Comment: @Catherine I didn't see that one. Possibly the TextView's are in the 2nd layout? And they need to be put in the 1st layout?

Comment: Im working on android Studio and all these elements are in the fragment_login.xml it creates, so If I do not set the content view to that layout, it doesnt find the elements, the weird thing is that instead from mainactivity I can access fragment_main.xml elements

Comment: Still not working, the way I see this is like (Im C++ programmer) namespaces more or less, so if I dont set the SetContentView to the fragment, it doesnt find the elements so their value is null.

The problem I do not understand, is that if the oncreate does not finish with the setview setted to activity_login, the app gives me a FC

Comment: Which view are your elements in? `activity_login` or `fragment_login`? Why don't you post your crash stack trace?